# Drools and rules quality

Tags: jakarta-ee, drools, drools-guvnor

Apart from Drools Guvnor (which we cannot use for now), is there a way to control the quality of the DRL code - like we would do after compilation with something like SonarQube, or at authoring (with checkstyle)?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thx!